# C# inputs an ASCII character to the TextBox when I press Backspace

Tags: c#

I have used e.Handled bool of KeyPress event and let e.KeyChar only be D0-D9, ',' and Back. But then my program started inputting an ASCII character into the TextBox instead of erasing the most recent char when I pressed Backspace. Then I assigned;

`if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back) {textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "\b"}`

to erase the most recent char that was inputted. It still decided to input a weird ASCII character instead of erasing anything.

Comment: String concatenation can never end up *removing* something from a string.

Comment: idc I solved the issue check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow characters in `'0'..'9'` range only, while keeping all the other logic intact (for instance, if you select *several* characters and then press "BackSpace" only selection will be removed, not the last character) you can handle unwanted characters only:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  e.Handled = e.KeyChar >= ' ' && (e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9');
}
```

Note, that `e.KeyChar >= ' '` allowes all command characters (BS included)

Comment: this isn't what I am looking for. And also check my own answer. I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

this worked:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, (textBox1.Text.Length - 1));
        }
```

Comment: Add `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)` check: you should do nothing on *empty* string

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following code.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back &&
            (e.KeyChar < (char)Keys.D0 || e.KeyChar > (char)Keys.D9))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```